# Appending constant string before to a list of string in Python

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I need to append the same list before every element in list

```py
list1 = ['foo', 'fob', 'faz', 'funk']

string = 'bar'
```

*magic*

```py
list2 = ['barfoo', 'barfob', 'barfaz', 'barfunk']
```

Comment: `list2 = [string + s for s in list1]`

Answer (score 4):

Simple, concatenation and list comprehension should do the job.

```
newList = [string+word for word in list1]
```

output

```
['barfoo', 'barfob', 'barfaz', 'barfunk']
```

Answer (score 0):

It would  be a good idea to use comprehension for this

```
list2 = [string+i for i in list1]
```